# which ruby version should i use with sass on windows 64-bit

Tags: ruby, sass, version

First of all i just want to **install ruby to use sass**.
My os is Windows 7 64-bit.

Like recommended on the [Sass website](http://sass-lang.com/install):

> The fastest way to get Ruby on your Windows computer is to use [Ruby
>   Installer](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/)

but here it is not clear which version to use. Quote from the Ruby website:

> If you don’t know what version to install and you’re getting started
>   with Ruby, we recommend you use Ruby 2.1.X installers.
>   [...]
>   The 64-bit versions of Ruby are relatively new on the Windows
>   area and not all the packages have been updated to be compatible with
>   it. To use this version you will require some knowledge about
>   compilers and solving dependency issues, which might be too
>   complicated if you just want to play with the language."

So normally I would install version **Ruby 2.2.3 (x64)** (which is the newest by now) but after reading the website I tend to **Ruby 2.1.7** (not even Ruby 2.1.7 (x64))

*I really searched a lot on this topic with google but was not able to get any profound information.*

Comment: You should use [LibSass](http://sass-lang.com/libsass), which is much faster than Ruby Sass. I use [Grunt Sass](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass) as implementation and will never switch back to Ruby again ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First question: x86_64 or 32 bits

In my experience you should focus on the gem you want to use. Maybe some gems with C code are not ready to be used/compiled on x86_64 OS.

the sass is written in ruby and it depends on yard and maruku (source : https://github.com/sass/sass/blob/stable/sass.gemspec)

maruku doesn't seem to have any dependencies (https://github.com/bhollis/maruku/blob/master/maruku.gemspec) and is written in ruby.

I have looked for yard and it seems that it is a full ruby gem without any  dependencies.

That means that the ruby version OS you use shouldn't be a problem (there is no compilation of C code to be done ...).

The other question is the ruby version.

The problem could come from the Ruby 2.2.3 version (32 bits or 64 bits)
This version is relatively new with some changes that needed some adjustments for some gems.

So use 32 bits you can use all the gems you want, and don't try to use the last version of ruby unless you want to try the latest functionalities that have been implemented.

**TL;DR:** use the Ruby 2.1X installers as they say.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time to answer! Actually i _switched from Ruby Sass to LibSass_ (thx @Frenk) - that's why its not necessary for me use Ruby anymore. But again: **THX !**